# CKEditor how to add a selectPage listener

Tags: events, plugins, ckeditor

I want to add a listener of selectPage event to my CKEditor plugin, but so far I'm unable to get it to work. The plugin works fine but my listener is not working. The alert below never gets called.

The code:

```
    var dialog = function(editor) {

        editor.on('selectPage', function(e) {
            alert("Page changed");
        });

         // rest of the plugin code
    }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you'll have to add it in the dialog definition, not on the dialog object or the editor object.

```
return {
     title : editor.lang.googlemaps.title,
     minWidth : 500,
     minHeight : 460,
     onLoad : function()
     {
        theDialog = this;

        // Act on tab switching
        theDialog.on('selectPage', function (e)
           {
              if (CKEDITOR.env.ie7Compat)
                 fixIE7display();
```